# Why is my VBA code not appending data but instead replacing data in the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long

Dim wksSource As Worksheet, wksDest As Worksheet

Dim source1 As Range, target1 As Range, source2 As Range, target2 As Range

Set wksSource = Workbooks("2021 Tracker.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3")

Set wksDest = Workbooks("Jan Tracker).xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastrow = wksSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

lastrow2 = wksDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).row

Set source1 = wksSource.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

Set source2 = wksSource.Range("B2:B" & lastrow)

Set target1 = wksDest.Range("E" & lastrow2)

Set target2 = wksDest.Range("F" & lastrow2)

source1.Copy: target1.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

source2.Copy: target2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

This code replaces data in columns E and F of destination workbook, but i want it to append to it. Please help.

Comment: Add one to the last row?

Comment: @RyanWildry - sorry didn't get you

Comment: You are finding the last row. If you have say A1:A10 filled out, you want to start writing on row 11, not 10. This code finds the last row, not the first blank row. You probably need to add 1 to your last row.

Comment: Your code determines the next row in column A of the destination worksheet: `lastrow2 = wksDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row`. But you are pasting to columns E and F. Therefore the last row in column A doesn't change and that results in over-writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code determines the next row in column A of the destination worksheet: lastrow2 = wksDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row. But you are pasting to columns E and F. Therefore the last row in column A doesn't change and that results in over-writing.

I have re-written your code to make it more transparent. I think this kind of syntax will make it easier for you to spot errors like the one that you asked about. It may take a little more time to set up but the time is well invested.

```
Sub AppendData()

    Dim wksSource As Worksheet                  ' Source sheet
    Dim wksTarget As Worksheet                  ' Target sheet
    Dim Source1 As Range
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' last row

    Set wksSource = Workbooks("2021 Tracker.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3")
    With wksSource
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Source = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rl, "B"))
    End With

    Set wksTarget = Workbooks("Jan Tracker).xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With wksTarget
        Set Target = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With

    Source.Copy Deestination:=Target
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @variatus. I tried this way and it worked. So if there are more source and target columns, we set those in the "with" loop correct using .Cells(Rl, "C/D/....") , correct?  [P.S: I also figured if i change my lastrow2 formulae to 5 instead of 1, it picks the correct row)

Comment: Yes, 2 = column B, 5 = E. Within a `With` block all items *can* be linked to the object defined with `With` with a leading period. That saves a lot of repetition and that makes reading easier, together with correct indentation. However, if you want to add more columns you should try to include them in the range you already set, such as `Source` which now has 2 columns but could have 25 without adding any code, just changing references in the existing.